# Can I load certain records while querying into another table?

Tags: hive

I have a table in Hive having ID, events (IN/out), time, date.

Now I have to query for records were for a particular ID display the IN and OUT timings.

Now for few records there will be IN time but no OUT time and vice versa.

I need to write a query were I have to query these uncorrelated records and put them into another table.

I hope I am making sense.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you mean you need to select the records for which the IN or OUT values are missing and then load them into a different table? What do you mean by uncorrelated?

Comment: yes.. I meant uncorrelated as in certain ID's do not have either In time or OUT time. those incomplete records.. I need to put it into another table. like a temp table

Answer (score 1):

Try the below :

```
  insert into temp_table select colA,colB,colC from ( select *,count(*) as cnt from TABLE_A group by id having cnt <2  ) as counts  ;
```